# How do you call a method that overrides a parent classes' method because it doesn't want the functionality

Tags: javascript, oop, overriding, terminology

This is a question about terminology in OOP.

Lets assume you have two classes `A` and `B`, with

```
class A extends B {}
```

Now `B` has a method called `doSomething()`, which it calls in its `constructor`.

```js
class B {
  constructor() {
    this.doSomething();
  }
  doSomething() {
    /* some functionality almost all classes extending B need */
  }
}
```

Now unfortunately `A` neither wants nor needs what happens when B's constructor calls `doSomething()`. It is even harmful to instances of `A`.

Object orientation offers the option to **overwrite** (or is it *override*?) the method in the inheriting class:

```js
class A extends B {
  constructor() {
    super(); // calls the contructor of B
  }
  doSomething() {
    this.doNothing();
  }
  doNothing() { 
    return;
  }
}
```

**My question:**

Is there a specific term in object orientation that describes exactly this way of overwriting/overriding an inherited method with a method that neutralizes the inherited methods functionality by basically doing *nothing*? How do you call `A`'s `doSomething()`?

Comment: "*overwrite (or is it override?)*" - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/8651562/1048572 for that

Comment: @Bergi thanks for that part. Any idea as of the main question? Is it a `stub`, a `dummy`, what is it called? I'd assume there is a specific term for such a method.

Comment: Regarding that, I have no idea. The terms [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and [noop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) appear related, but the scheme as a whole seems uncommon enough to not have an established name. Usually, overriding is used the other way round.